# Why are successful human rock climbers so dissimilar to Hominidae primates who spend extended time periods climbing?

Tags: evolution, zoology, muscles

In rock climbing, the sport considers the [Ape Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ape_index) when evaluating the factors critical for success.

However, the majority of successful climbers are lithe and slim with less than 8% body fat.  As one professional described it

> “I feel very pressured to be thinner for climbing. I’m very strong, but I will likely never be thin, and I think that it holds me back…I don’t have that classic thin, long-limbed climber body…”

However, this seems completely at odds with the primates that we see on documentaries and in zoos which appear to be heavy, muscular, powerful and with considerable upper body strength.

Professional human climbers, while strong, rarely have significant quantities of muscle (Bodybuilder-esque) on their skeleton. They seek a power to weight ratio through weight-loss.

What accounts for this difference in development?  How do primates move such heavy masses through the upper canopy and why have they not evolved slimmer, smaller or more lithe frames?

Comment: I don't understand. Monkeys that are particularly agile at climbing tend to be very thin as well. A famously agile monkey species is the [spider monkey](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Spider+Monkeys&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1uIG7so3SAhVJ0mMKHaUoC2oQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=712).

Comment: Orangutan, Gorilla,  Chimpanzee...

Comment: Gorillas typically are pretty bad at climbing. I think you make the mistake to put all primates into a single pack and assume they are all alike and are all good climbers and then you make comparison with humans. A human is probably a better climber than a gorilla.

Comment: Remi...please dont make uninformed comments.  If you have an academic answer backed up with references then please make it otherwise assumptions benefit no one. http://www.berggorilla.org/en/gorillas/general/everyday-life/do-gorillas-often-climb-trees/ Gorillas can spend 20% of their day climbing

Comment: Venture, humans don't have exoskeletons (and you call others uninformed?) Please don't come here and be rude. We like questions, and we like answering good ones, but Remi.b is right that you've grouped a large number of species then compared them to one. You have your answer in your question. Finally, how closely related is climbing rocks to climbing trees? If trees disappear and primates have to resort to living on cliff faces, you'll have your definitive answer in a few million years maybe.

Comment: Do gorillas spend their time rock climbing?

Comment: @Seeds: Do ANY primates (other than a small subset of H. sapiens) spend much time rock climbing?  Some, but by no means all, of them spend a lot of time climbing trees & other jungle vegetation, but that's rather different from rock climbing.

Comment: @jamesqf Aye, that was the point of my question. H Saps do it infrequently, for recreation, all the other apes climb/swing in trees, which is a totally different activity. (closer to some of the things gymnasts do, like the ring thing)

Comment: I have specifically said Hominadae @anongoodnurse.  I did call others uninformed to state that gorillas are poor climbers.  I stand by that.  It was uninformed. I made a mistake in using the word exoskeleton but that doesn't make Remi's assumptions and your own any less rude. If you cannot answer, simply don't comment on the question.  I have grouped a large number of species, you are right, they are called the Hominidae family and all display similar traits and characteristics in climbing abilities.

Comment: @Venture2099 I don't want to fuel the discussion any more... but I am pretty bad at some things I sometimes spent a lot of time on. The fact that gorillas spend a lot of time climbing does not make them good at it. In fact, maybe if they were better they would have to spend less time doing it and more resting. You were asking for competitive climbers. Just because someone has a better Ape index it does not make them automatically a more avid climber.

Comment: And no source has been posted to prove that Gorillas are bad at climbing.  It was merely an assumption by a commenter, like much of this discussion thread.

Comment: Of course it varies from one species to the other. The silverback typically don't climb. Few branches would be able to hold their weight anyway. Other gorillas don't climb much in general (although see Western lowland gorillas do climb quite a bit) except for playing and foraging on fruits. They are in any way very bad in comparison with spider monkeys or other monkeys that are thinner and have longer limbs.

Comment: No one is comparing them with Monkeys.  Just you.

Comment: @Venture2099 Your OP says "primates" in every place except where you mention an "Ape Index". If you want comparisons only to apes, then say apes, don't say primates. You changed your title *after* the comment thread started talking about monkeys and then wonder why people are still on monkeys.

Comment: Actually I said Hominidae

Comment: There is an edit history here. You did not say Hominidae in the body of your question, and you added it to the title only *after* @Remi.b made a comment about monkeys.

Comment: After his first comment.  And I clarified in the comments as well but he kept referencing monkeys. *shrug*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rock-climber myself I’ll attempt to answer:  The *selection* criteria for competitive rock-climbing is exclusively based on sustain non-resting, extremely challenging moves up a rock-face.  The two most challenging aspects are 1) ability to ‘crimp’ (climbing term) on micro-holds without slipping and 2) *being able to keep that up without resting throughout the climb*.  I personally have a real problem with the later, because of my weight.

Primates selection criteria is not isolated to non-resting climbs.  They don’t get penalized for sitting on the branch.

Comment: I have to say, as someone who did a bit of climbing now & then, that the idea of competitive rock climbing just boggles my mind.  It seems to run contrary to everything I enjoyed about climbing...

Comment: @Venture2099 If you think this answer answered your question then upvote and accept it instead of posting unnecessary comments.

Comment: I will post the comments that I see fit and I will mark the question as answered when I think it is appropriate.